# Can't run android hello world app in android avd, but can do it in genymotion. why?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

Create Android Hello World application in Eclipse from scratch, but when I run it, receive many errors. But when run in genymotion it's ok. what's wrong?
[image: android sdk manager]
[image: continuation]
[image: android virtual device]

maybe I need to install some folders? I don't install many of them because have not many place in PC and not fast internet connection - only minimum for development.

Android LogCat:

> 

```
05-19 20:56:11.620: E/PowerManagerService-JNI(1270): Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
05-19 20:56:11.620: E/Installer(1270): connection failed
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/SurfaceFlinger(929): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270): ******************************************
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270): ************ Failure starting bootstrap service
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270):     at com.android.server.firewall.IntentFirewall.readRulesDir(IntentFirewall.java:271)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270):     at com.android.server.firewall.IntentFirewall.<init>(IntentFirewall.java:114)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.main(ActivityManagerService.java:1804)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:196)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270):     at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1179)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/System(1270):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: WindowManager
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at com.android.server.display.LocalDisplayAdapter$LocalDisplayDevice.getDisplayDeviceInfoLocked(LocalDisplayAdapter.java:147)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.handleDisplayDeviceAddedLocked(DisplayManagerService.java:852)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.handleDisplayDeviceAdded(DisplayManagerService.java:841)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.access$1100(DisplayManagerService.java:96)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService$DisplayAdapterListener.onDisplayDeviceEvent(DisplayManagerService.java:1281)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at com.android.server.display.DisplayAdapter$1.run(DisplayAdapter.java:108)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270): Error reporting crash
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:84)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
05-19 20:56:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
05-19 20:56:11.840: E/AudioFlinger(1294): no wake lock to update!
05-19 20:56:11.840: E/AudioFlinger(1294): int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
05-19 20:56:12.000: E/memtrack(1292): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
05-19 20:56:12.000: E/android.os.Debug(1292): failed to load memtrack module: -2
05-19 20:56:12.620: E/EmojiFactory_jni(1292): Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found
```

Comment: Post what errors you receive.